# Repeating CSS grid layout with named columns for every X number of rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid where the there is 2 named columns (`[name]` and `[crown]`) and an unknown number of rows. Each row will have a `name` element and may or may not have a `crown` element.  What I want to happen is for the maximum number of rows be 3, so that when there is more than 3 rows, they appear in a new adjacent set of 2 columns.

For example, with the following data:

```js
[
  { name: A, crown: true },
  { name: B, crown: false },
  { name: C, crown: true },
  { name: D, crown: false },
  { name: E, crown: true }
]
```

It would appear like this:

[image]

I've tried messing around with grid-auto-flow, grid-auto-rows, and other properties, but pretty much everything I try ends up like this:

[image]

The elements are created using a Mustache template, so without first taking the input data and looping through / modifying it (which can be done but is not preferable), I cannot assign different classes/column numbers to individual elements in order to place them in specific columns.

Is there any other way I can achieve the result in the first image?

Here is a sample of the code I am trying to use:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [name] 1fr [crown] 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: min-content;
}

.grid > * {
  padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;
}

.grid > .name {
  grid-column: name;
}

.grid > .crown {
  grid-column: crown;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="name">A</div>
  <div class="crown">#</div>
  <div class="name">B</div>
  <div class="name">C</div>
  <div class="crown">#</div>
  <div class="name">D</div>
  <div class="name">E</div>
  <div class="crown">#</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please refator the question. Unable to understand

Comment: @vithushaji My apologies, I have reworded it to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: The code nor logic that generates the HTML is not at all relevant to the question that is concerning the way in which that HTML is styled. I suggest removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying `grid-template-columns: [name] 1fr [crown] 1fr`. Therefore, you will always receive two fractions in the end.

I advise you to wrap divs with a `[name]` and a `[crown]` in an additional div, which will be like one cell. And with rule `grid-auto-flow: column`, we can get the desired result.

```css
.grid {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.grid_item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [name] 1fr [crown] 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.grid_item > * {
    padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;
}

.grid_item .crown {
    color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid_item">
        <div class="name">A</div>
        <div class="crown">#</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_item">
        <div class="name">B</div>
        <div class="crown"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_item">
        <div class="name">C</div>
        <div class="crown">#</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_item">
        <div class="name">D</div>
        <div class="crown"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_item">
        <div class="name">E</div>
        <div class="crown">#</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @epiqu1n, Glad the solution helped.